# Why does separation of different colours increase in higher order maxima?

Tags: optics, visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation, diffraction

In a question on the difference between the 1st and 2nd order maxima formed when light of 2 different  Wavelengths is incident on a diffraction grating, the marking scheme mentions that separation of the maxima of the wavelength increases with n, with the reason that $\Delta \theta$ increases with $n$ from the equation:

$$d\sin(\theta)=n\lambda $$

I am unable to understand or prove this. Can anyone give me an intuitive or mathematical explanation for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\sin \theta = n\lambda /D$, then
$$ \frac{d (\sin \theta)}{d\lambda} = \frac{n}{D}$$
$$\cos \theta \frac{d\theta}{d\lambda}= \frac{n}{D}$$
$$\frac{d\theta}{d\lambda}= \frac{n}{D\sqrt{1-\sin^2 \theta}}$$
$$\frac{d\theta}{d\lambda}= \frac{n}{D\sqrt{1-n^2\lambda^2/D^2}}$$

Thus the angular separation between two wavelengths, separated by $\Delta \lambda$ becomes larger, for larger values of $n$.
$$\Delta\theta \sim \left(\frac{n}{D\sqrt{1-n^2\lambda^2/D^2}}\right)\ \Delta \lambda$$

Answer (score 1):

If $\lambda_2=\lambda_1+\Delta\lambda$ where $\Delta\lambda<<\lambda_1$ (which isn't really necessary)

then for first order you have the equation with:
\begin{equation}
d\sin(\theta_1)=\lambda_1\\
d\sin(\theta_2)=\lambda_1+\Delta\lambda
\end{equation}
now second order:
\begin{equation}
d\sin(\theta_3)=2\lambda_1\\
d\sin(\theta_4)=2\lambda_1+2\Delta\lambda
\end{equation}

the easiest way, I guess is to see the $n\Delta\lambda$